# Vue.js: Year Slider won't update data properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slider

I have created a year slider that should change the data in a scatter plot based on the year chosen. However, when I change the year the data in the scatterplot appear on top of the previously selected year. So I have data from two years in the scatter plot, which I should not have.

This is the store.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    selectedYear: 1984,
    selectedStates: [],
    income: [],
    rates: [],
},
  mutations: {
    changeSelectedYear (state, year) {
      state.selectedYear = year;
    },
    changeSelectedState(state, val) {
      state.selectedStates.push(val);
    }   
  },
  getters: {
    selectedYear: (state) => state.selectedYear,
    selectedStates: (state) => state.selectedStates,
    income (state) {
      let result = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < state.income.length; i++) {
        if (state.selectedYear in state.income[i]) {
          result.push({
            state: state.income[i].State,
            value: +state.income[i][state.selectedYear]
          })
        }
      }
      return result;
    },
   Rates (state) {
      let result = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < state.rates.length; i++) {
        if (state.selectedYear in state.rates[i]) {
          result.push({
            state: state.rates[i].State,
            value: +state.rates[i][state.selectedYear]
          })
        }
      }
      return result;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    loadData({state}) {
      d3.csv('./income.csv').then((data) => { 
        state.Income = data;
      })

      d3.csv('./Rates.csv').then((data) => { 
        state.Rates = data;
      })
    },
  }
})

export default store;
```

This is the YearSlider file:

```
  <div>
    <label for="range-year">Year Selection</label>
    <b-form-input id="range-year" v-model="selectedYear" type="range" min="1984" max="2014"></b-form-input>
    <div class="mt-2">Selected Year: {{ selectedYear }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'YearSlider',
  props: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  mounted() {
  },
  methods: {
  },
  computed: {
    selectedYear: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.getters.selectedYear;
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$store.commit('changeSelectedYear', val);
      },
    },
  },
  watch: {
  },
}
</script>
```

Can anyone take a look and recommend any solution? Thank you!

This how the data appear:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide any screenshots or errors to understand the problem clearly?

Comment: Hi! I did include a screenshot of how the scatterplot looks when using the slider. And I don't get any error messages in the terminal